# grant IIS APPPOOL wrecked my SQL Server windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

I am pretty sure that following a quick hack to get around a projects permissions with using `icacls <path_to_site> /grant "IIS APPPOOL\<app_pool_name>"(CI)(OI)(M)`

I ran

```
 icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\ /grant "IIS APPPOOL\DEFAULTAPPPOOL":(CI)(OI)(M)
```

Now I **cannot** **connect** to **sql server** with **windows authentication!**

Yes, I was not thinking, but "whatever" now I want to revert this and NOT have this grant, so I was reading and reading.. and not having too much fun.

1. How can I revert to the default ?
   OR
2. Is it easier to just uninstall /reinstall IIS  ( local machine, nothing in IIS except 1 website which will get re-created

Comment: This is when I realized that it had to be from my IIS grant   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723623/application-cannot-open-sql-connection-when-on-iis

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: "The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context ( microsoft sql server) "

Comment: Repair of SQL Server 2014 did not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repair did not work with sql server 2014.

**I installed sql server 2012 and that worked.**

No time to troubleshoot it any longer.